# Scheduled Job Does Not Seem To Be Running

Tags: scheduled-apex

I have a Scheduled Job that doesn't seem to be running, and can't figure out why.

When I go to Monitor > Jobs > Scheduled Jobs, two of my scheduled jobs are the following:

[image]

1. "Queued SMS Engine" is supposed to run hourly.  You can see that it was last run at 2:02 PM and the next run will be at 3:02 PM
2. "CCx Client Surveys Engine" is supposed to run daily.  You can see that it was last run at 12:00pm today, and will next be run at 12:00pm tomorrow.

... Seems OK so far ... **In practice, though, we're noticing the results of the SMS Engine running each hour, but the work done by the Client Surveys Engine never actually happens.**

Time to check out the Monitor > Jobs > Apex Jobs page.  And here's what we see there:

[image]

And sure enough, while there's a log entry for the hourly SMS Job, there is no evidence that the Client Surveys job actually happens at the expected time.

Have you see this before?  Any idea what I should be looking at or debugging?
What parts of my code would be helpful to look at when debugging this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen that but when I am debugging scheduled batches, I typically schedule it via the dev console to run in 2 minutes time, and then watch the logs - even if if something isn't written to the jobs queue, you should see it in the logs for the running user (which would be you if created via Dev Console)

Comment: This worked brilliantly.  Turned out that the job **was** being run, but an early bug was stopping it midstream.